# Permutation Matrix properties

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, determinant

How do I show that the 
$det(P_{\pi})=sgn(\pi)$ when $P_{\pi}$ is defined by: 
$$
p_{ij}=
 \begin{cases}
  1, & \text{when }i = \pi(j);\\
  0, & \text{otherwise}.
 \end{cases}
$$
I am not sure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can row reduce $P_{\pi}$ to the identity by repeatedly switching rows.  Switching rows corresponds to multiplying $\pi$ by a transposition.  How does the determinant change when you switch two rows?

Comment: It changes the sign of the determinant. How would you generalize this to $nxn$ matrices ?

Comment: What I said works for any size matrices